# Aim a certain line of CSS at a specific tag

Tags: css, copy, paste, repeat

Hopefully this makes sense but is it possible to point a line of css to a certain tag?

e.g I have this code

```
.about h2 {
color: black;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 26px;
}
```

I have a H2 in another class called "Projects" and want a margin-top:20px; in the above code^. So instead of copying and pasting it can I just add it into the above and make it only apply to the "Projects" H2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "want a margin-top:20px; in the above code" means u want margin-top for the about class, this is what you should use

```
.about h2, .Projects h2 {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.about h2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is:

```
<style>
.about h2 {
color: black;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 26px;
}

.about.projects h2{
margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>

<div class="about">
    <h2>About</h2>
</div>

<div class="projects about">
    <h2>About projects</h2>
</div>
```

In this way you can reuse .about style in .projects

Answer (score 0):

If you want your css to apply to only an `h2` in the class `Projects`, you can do this:

```
h2.Projects {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```